# Git - como ignorar arquivos dentro de uma pasta

Tags: git

Como eu faco para versionar a pasta sem versionar todos os arquivos que estão dentro dela?

já tentei de várias formas e não consigo, ou versiona os arquivos ou para de versionar a pasta. Preciso dela criada para funcionamento correto do projeto.

A pasta está na raiz do projeto.

Não quero versionar arquivos de cache de views

minhas tentativas:

```
views-cache/*
views-cache/
views-cache/**/*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie um arquivo `.gitignore` dentro da pasta `views-cache` e coloque como conteúdo dele:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

isso fará com que todos os arquivos da pasta sejam ignorados exceto o proprio `.gitignore`
depois use o comando `git add views-cache/.gitignore`

Answer (score 2):

crie um arquivo de texto e salve com o nome `.gitignore` dentro da pasta
em cada linha do arquivo coloque o nome do arquivo ou o regex dos arquivos que deseja ignorar:

```
views-cache/*
```

documentação: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

caso já tenha comitado a pasta e/ou arquivos execute o comando abaixo

```
git rm --cached -r /views-cache
```

o `-r`é de recursivo, ou seja, remove os arquivos dentro da pasta também

Comment: eu já tenho o .gitignore e ja tentei dessa forma que você falou e ele para de versionar a pasta, quero que pare só os arquivos dentro da pasta

Comment: você já commitou algumas vez esses arquivos?

Comment: acabei de testar com essa linha: views-cache/* . deletei a pasta .git, dei um git init novamente, um add e um commit e os arquivos de dentro a views-cache foram comitados, ou seja, nao foram ignorados como eu preciso

Comment: Como está a sua árvore de diretórios?

Comment: raiz->views-cache

Comment: arquivos que são gerados: views-cache/registers-brands-update.793678081f3c5a6081d5061f3df4e175.rtpl.php

Comment: atualizei a resposta, veja lá

Comment: nao deu certo, sumiu a pasta views-cache